# how does "streaming" over http work?

Tags: c#, .net, streaming, video-streaming, audio-streaming

Each time I encounter the term streaming, the concept confuses me. Can you link me to any documentation about the concept and examples? (.net and c#)

Comment: stream = river; jump in where you want, watch/listen (e.g. swim) as long as you want, jump out when done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This article on Silverlight Streaming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee336025.aspx) Might be what you are looking for.

You may find playing with [Expression Encoder](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/Encoder4_Overview.aspx) is also a good place to start.